# Using mod rewrite to clean my URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know this question may have been asked many times before and I may be down-voted a lot but trust me, this was my last resort after testing and reading many articles on google.

I have the url `/index.php?action=gametypes&mode=control-point` which  I would like to rewrite to `/gametypes/control-point`.

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^gametypes/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?action=gametypes&mode=$1[L]
```

Now when I visit `/gametypes/control-point` I get a 404 not found and the URL shows rewrites to `localhost/thecoremc/gametypes/control-point/index.php`. It's a 404 because there is no index.php. Any idea what I could use to successfully load the page?

Extra info: I'm running my localhost with the domain `localhost/thecoremc/` and apache `2.4.4`

Thanks!

Comment: `/index.php?action`...?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this instead...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?action=$1&mode=$2 [L]
```

I used a dummy-domain, which was http://www.domain.com/index.php?action=gametypes&mode=control-point to achieve this.

Based on your comment, try this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /thecoremc/index.php?action=$1&mode=$2 [L]
```

which is based on: `http://localhost/thecoremc/index.php?action=gametypes&mode=control-point`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `/thecoremc/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /thecoremc/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&mode=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This worked however all styles are missing. With the inspector,  I saw that the URL for all the links were `http://localhost/thecoremc/gametypes/control-point/(paths)`

Comment: For css/js/images use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. OR else You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This might be helpful for your work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)&name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^articles\.php$ /article/%1/%2? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^article/([^-]+)/([^-]+)$ /articles.php?article_id=$1&article_name=$2 [L]
```

The above code will redirect

```
localhost/a1/articles.php?id=10&name=xyz
```

to

```
localhost/article/10/xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule gametypes/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?action=$1&mode=$2
```